# したい思った? What is this odd construct?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs

I have a Question -> Response exercise in my textbook. The context is a job interview at a convenience store. I think the meaning is "why do you want this job?" but the way the Japanese is worded seems odd to me.

Can somebody translate this for me please?

> こちらでアルバイトを　したい思った理由は　何ですか。

It is したい思った which is confusing to me. "want to have thought"?

Comment: Are you sure your textbook says したい思った理由, not したい**と**思った理由?

Comment: @Chocolate Good point. I guess I should edit the と into my answer?

Comment: @user3856370 そうですね。もしかしたら、textbookのタイポかもしれませんね・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> こちらでアルバイトを　したいと思った理由は　何ですか。
>   What's the reason you think you want to do a part-time job here?

- The job interviewer (A) is asking the reason from the job interviewee (B), not asking what B wants to do, because A already knows that B wants to do a part-time job here.
- Why does A know B's intention already? Because, A has got B's application for the job already.
- When did B think he wanted to do a part-time job here? Before submitting the application for the job.
- Then B thought of the part-time job **in the past**, so the phrase アルバイトをしたいと**思った** is used instead of アルバイトをしたいと**思う**.

**That's why the tense differs between English and 日本語｛にほんご｝.**

Answer (score 2):

たい is modifying する not 思う in this sentence, so したいと思う means "think you want to do", not "want to think you do".

> こちらでアルバイトをする -> do part-time work here.
>   こちらでアルバイトをしたい -> want to do part-time work here.
>   こちらでアルバイトをしたいと思った -> think you want to do part-time work here.
>   こちらでアルバイトをしたいと思った理由は -> the reason you think you want to do part-time work here
>   こちらでアルバイトをしたいと思った理由は何ですか -> What's the reason you think you want to do part-time work here?

Why it uses 思った rather than 思う is something I don't quite understand though.

Comment: `Why it uses 思った rather than 思う` >> In English you'd also say like "What motivat**ed** /prompt**ed** you to apply for this job?", no?

Comment: I see your point, but the 'applying' has already happened by the time of the interview. The 'thinking they want the job' is ongoing. Anyway, I'm happy that 思った makes sense.